# i have written a program to manage student data and overloaded operators but i got an error free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c++

```
class student
{
    private:
        int RollNo;
        string Name;
    public:
        student(){}
        student(int rn, string n)
        {
            RollNo = rn;
            Name = n;
        }
        ~student(){}
        int getRollNo() { return RollNo; }
        string getName() { return Name; }
    friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream & ifs, student &s);
    friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream & ofs, student &s);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream & is, student &s);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, student &s);

};
```

//overloading operator>> for reading from file using input

```
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream &ifs, student &s)
{
    file stream object
    ifs.read((char*) &s,sizeof(s));
    return ifs;
}
```

//overloading operator<< for writing to file output file stream object

```
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream & ofs, student &s)
{
    ofs.write((char*) &s,sizeof(s));
    return ofs;
}
```

//overloading operator<< to write to output stream using its

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, student &s)
{
    object and  student object
    os<<"Roll No. = "<<s.RollNo<<endl;
    os<<"Name = "<<s.Name<<endl;
    return os;
}
```

//overloading operator>> to write into student object using

```
istream& operator>>(istream & is, student &s)
{
    inputstream object
    cout<<"Enter R0ll No.: ";
    is>>s.RollNo;
    cout<<"Enter Name: ";
    is>>s.Name;
    return is;
}
```

//main block

```
int main()
{
    student s1(112,"abhimanyu"),s2(123,"abc");
    student temp;
    ofstream ofileobject("abc.txt",ios:: out | ios::trunc);
    ofileobject<<s1<<s2;
    ofileobject.close();
    ifstream ifileobject("abc.txt",ios::in);
    ifileobject>>temp;
    cout<<temp;
    ifileobject>>temp;
    cout<<temp;
    ifileobject.close();

}
```

i am working on a program to read and write student data to 
file with insertion and extraction operators overloaded for
both istream/ostream and ifstream/ofstream but i got an 
error "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer"

i tried hard but unable to get a solution to this invalid pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read/write non-POD objects, like std::string, from/to file using `of.write((char*)&obj,sizeof(obj));`

You need to properly read/write such objects by value, i.e. something like:

```
of.write(str.data(), str.length() + 1);
```

Where +1 is for writing `'\0'` terminator. Or just using objects overloaded `<<` operator. I.e.:

```
of << str;
```

Edit:

So basically you file operators should look like:

```
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream &ifs, student &s)
{
    ifs >> s.RollNo >> s.Name;
    return ifs;
}

ofstream& operator<<(ofstream & ofs, student &s)
{
    ofs << s.RollNo << s.Name;
    return ofs;
}
```

Comment: sir i am at very early stage of programming currenty in class 12th please elaborate or make the necessary changes

Comment: Read about POD: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType You can  simply read/write only POD types. For all other types you should read/write each member separately, either by using that member's overloaded `<<`/`>>` operators or some other means.